# How to pass variable to my code

Tags: php, arrays

This is code:

```
<?php
$url_edit = '$i';
$url_delete = '$j';
$form['table'] = '$eval_var'.'='.'array($url_edit,$url_delete);' ;
?>
<table>
  <?php
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
?>
<tr>
<?php
    for($j=0;$j<=10;$j++){
      eval($form['table']);
      echo '<td>'.$eval_var[0].'</td>'.'<td>'.$eval_var[1].'</td>';
    }
    ?>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Expecting result:

0   0   0   1   0   2   0   3   0   4   0   5   0   6   0   7   0   8   0   9   0   10
1   0   1   1   1   2   1   3   1   4   1   5   1   6   1   7   1   8   1   9   1   10
2   0   2   1   2   2   2   3   2   4   2   5   2   6   2   7   2   8   2   9   2   10
3   0   3   1   3   2   3   3   3   4   3   5   3   6   3   7   3   8   3   9   3   10
4   0   4   1   4   2   4   3   4   4   4   5   4   6   4   7   4   8   4   9   4   10
5   0   5   1   5   2   5   3   5   4   5   5   5   6   5   7   5   8   5   9   5   10
6   0   6   1   6   2   6   3   6   4   6   5   6   6   6   7   6   8   6   9   6   10
7   0   7   1   7   2   7   3   7   4   7   5   7   6   7   7   7   8   7   9   7   10
8   0   8   1   8   2   8   3   8   4   8   5   8   6   8   7   8   8   8   9   8   10
9   0   9   1   9   2   9   3   9   4   9   5   9   6   9   7   9   8   9   9   9   10
10  0   10  1   10  2   10  3   10  4   10  5   10  6   10  7   10  8   10  9   10  10

But it is showing:

$i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j
$i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j
$i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j
$i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j
$i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j
$i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j
$i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j
$i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j
$i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j
$i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j
$i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j  $i  $j

Where is the problem in code and why?

Note: it is working if I put:

```
$form['table'] = '$eval_var'.'='.'array($i,$j);' ;
```

But why how to make it work passing external  variables?

Comment: replace `echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>'.'<td>'.$j.'</td>';` with `echo '<td>'.$eval_var[0].'</td>'.'<td>'.$eval_var[1].'</td>';`

Comment: remove single quotes from $i and $j

Comment: I have to work with eval for my project. It is partial code of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you proper understanding:

To use string code inside eval always try to

a)put your variable inside(" code ") as a string

b) escape $ placing \ before it.

So, 100% correct code will be:

```
$url_edit = "\$i";
$url_delete = "\$j";
$form['table'] = "\$eval_var".'='."array($url_edit,$url_delete);" ;
```

Look at line 3. What is the meaning of it?

```
$form['table'] = "\$eval_var".'='."array(\$i,\$j);" ;
```

It satisfied conditions (a) and (b).

So fully correct code will be:

```
<?php
$url_edit = "\$i";
$url_delete = "\$j";
$form['table'] = "\$eval_var".'='."array($url_edit,$url_delete);" ;
?>
<table>
  <?php
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
?>
<tr>
<?php
    for($j=0;$j<=10;$j++){
      eval($form['table']);
      echo '<td>'.$eval_var[0].'</td>'.'<td>'.$eval_var[1].'</td>';
    }
    ?>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Hope you will understand it clearly. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whats the purpose of this, but you need to let`$url_edit` and `$url_delete` be interpolated first by using double quotes, then escape `$eval_var`.

```
$url_edit = '$i'; // string literals to be interpolated
$url_delete = '$j'; // this one as well
$form['table'] = "\$eval_var = array($url_edit,$url_delete);";
                // ^ escape this      ^         ^ let this be interpolated
```